# Smoothed surface shows odd lighting

Tags: mesh, shaders, lighting

I made this table for a game and it happens to have this weird lighting on the surface when I apply smooth shade.
[image: The problem]

[image: Model in Edit Mode]

Answer (score 1):

Smooth shade on a low poly object will always fail (why do you even want to smooth shade it? what do you expect from the smooth shading?)

If you want to bevel angles, you need (in addition to smooth shading) to add subdivision modifier and then add as many supporting loops as you need (that's a lot to learn btw).